# what can i add to wings that were frozen in a soy sauce to save them

Tags: substitutions

i was making stickey wings and the party was put off for a week, so I froze the wings in the soy sauce based maranade now im fixing them ans the salty taste is horrible, is there anything i can add to them or do to get ride of the high sodium taste

Comment: If you go by the [flavor star](http://www.cooksmarts.com/articles/study-flavor-profiles/), something bitter might help

Answer (score 3):

If there's sauce stuck to them, you could just wash them thoroughly. If they're seriously overmarinated, salty all the way through, you could try soaking in water to try to pull some of it back out.

If none of that works, Joe's suggestion of adding bitter flavors could work, up to a point, but it won't be the recipe you had in mind originally.

You could also add or serve with something bulky that isn't salty at all. This is a bit tricky with wings; it might have to be a sauce, since you can't exactly just toss in potatoes or vegetables and expect to eat it all together easily.